# Display message Google Sheets from Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to display a message on a google sheet. But I don't get it, and, after research here, in documentation, I don't get the answer.

I think that the problem is in "activate" the spreadsheet, where i need to display.

```
var SEGUIMIENTO = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MyTestediD");
var INF = SEGUIMIENTO.getSheetByName("NameOfSheet");
function TestMessage() {
  INF.activate();
  Browser.msgBox("Hello")
}
```

When i run.. nothing happen

I need the definition of Spreadsheet outside the function because I'm working in 2 Spreadsheet's by ID in more that one function.

i only need the correction in my code for display a simple message in the spreadsheet.

PD. i really cant find a simple example of that,

**Update**

This code it's part of a macro recorder of a Spreadsheet, the same "SpreadsheetApp.openById("MyTestediD");"

Comment: Welcome. The information about your case is incomplete. Is this code included on a bounded script or on a standalone script?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know why you try to 'activate' a sheet. If you want display a message I assume you want to do it in the user's current sheet, so:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Confirmation received.');
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser

> The methods in this class are only available for use in the context of a Google Spreadsheet. Please use [G Suite dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) instead.

As you can see, Google is nicely asking you to use [G Suite dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) instead of Class Browser, so be nice too and follow their request.

Comment: Yes, i wento to this page, and copy and paste, the firs code "onOpen" but i cant get a sinple msgbox in my spreadsheet... i don know if i must activcate in the clobal.. or what..

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want a message in a spreeadsheet, do you mean an alert message? If so, the answer is to use the code SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello.'); when the TestMessage function is executed

```js
var SEGUIMIENTO = SpreadsheetApp.openById("My TestediD");
var INF = SEGUIMIENTO.getSheetByName("NameOfSheet");
function TestMessage() {
  INF.activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello.');
}
```

Comment: Stack Snippet should be used only for runnable HTML/CSS/JavaScript. By the other hand, this answer basically suggest the same as this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53797181/1595451)